# Вместо иконок Font-Awesome отображаются квадраты

Tags: css, шрифты, иконки

Коллеги, плиз, подскажите как поправить работу с иконками?! Есть сайт https://market.bigvile.ru/ На нем не отображаются иконки.

Но если через просмотр кода я меняю `far` на `fa`, иконки отображаются! Как сделать изменения на всем сайте грамотно?!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какие у вас проблемы с исправлением far на fa?

Comment: Нужно HTML-ки подправить? Так это может сделать редактор, на чем ты пишешь?

Comment: Решено! Может кому понадобится: шаблон не работает с плагином Visual Composer. Отключил, иконки отображаются. Для того, чтобы найти откуда работает данная иконка: надо посмотреть код (правая кнопка мыши), навести курсор внизу где отображаются настройки css и будет виден путь из какого файла они подгружаются! Отличного творчества!